JSON Schema Validation of a Decimal Number in a Panda Dataframe
The following Python script must validate the number of decimal places in the records. In the schema, I am trying to define that it has 3 decimal places, using "multipleOf": 0.001.
I have a record with 5 decimal places: "scores": [1.12345]
It should report an error but it is returning:
Validation ok
     scores
0 1.12345

How can I fix this?
import jsonschema
import pandas as pd

schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "properties": {"scores": {"type": "number", "multipleOf": 0.001}},
}


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "scores": [1.12345],
    }
)

validator = jsonschema.Draft202012Validator(schema)

try:
    validator.validate(instance=df.to_dict("records"))
    print("Validation ok")

except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
    print(f"Validation error: {e.message}")

print(df)


I don't know the answer to this, but you should be careful using multipleOf with floating point, because floating point numbers are approximations.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Your validation is not successful because the type:array is defined incorrectly. Your scores array instance is never validated because the schema only knows about "scores": 1.000 OR [] at the root.
EDIT:
I didn't see you are using dataframes which are an array instance
Try this schema
schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": { "scores": {
         "type": "array", "items": {"type": "number", "multipleOf": 0.001 }}}}},
}

This would be equivalent to
[{"scores": [1.000, 1.235, 2.333]}]


Using it as suggested, it returns:
Validation error: [{'scores': 1.12345}] is not of type 'object'

I have to change something?

Dataframe is a list. Is tha why?
df.to_dict("records")
[{'scores': 1.12345}]


i modified the schema, try again

Sorry, guess my lack of panda knowledge is not helping here. Doesn't appear to work.  But I will say your schema is not correct for the data instance you are trying to validate. I think it may have something to do with how you are passing instance=df to the validator function. That's where my panda knowledge fails me.

With the last modification you made, it worked. Thanks!!!!

It worked with Jeremy's suggestion
import jsonschema
import pandas as pd

schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {"scores": {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "number", "multipleOf": 0.001}}},
    },
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "scores": [1.1234],
        }
    ]
)

validator = jsonschema.Draft202012Validator(schema)

try:
    validator.validate(instance=df.to_dict("records"))
    print("Validation ok")

except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
    print(f"Validation error: {e.message}")

print(df)


Thank you Jeremy!
